Next middleware doesn't pass cookies returned from server
I have a Django backend that returns an httpOnly cookie on successful login. This cookie is required for accessing protected routes in the Next app. I have a middleware that checks if a protected route is being accessed - if it is, then an api call is made to ensure that the user can access said page. Here's the code for that -
export default middleware = async (request) => {
  //check auth status if user tries to access protected routes
  if (PROTECTED_ROUTES.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    try {
      let res = await fetch(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL + "/authentication/check",
        { credentials: "include" }
      );

      //Go to login page if not signed in
      if (res.status !== 200) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(PAGE_ROUTES.LOGIN, request.url));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      //In case API fails or there is an exception, send them to login page
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(PAGE_ROUTES.LOGIN, request.url));
    }
  }
};


On login, I can see the cookie in the application tab under chrome dev tools. But when I try accessing a protected route, I get sent back to the login page, as the cookie is not being sent. Why is this happening? How can I make the middleware pass the cookie that is saved in the clients browser?

This is happening Because of the fact that this code is not being run on the client side.
You'll have to manually get and include the cookies on the headers/cookies.
I also see a bad practice in this code.
Instead of
      let res = await fetch(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL + "/authentication/check",
        { credentials: "include" }
      );

You should instead copy paste the same code here(or create a function  for that), to see the authentication status, like this:
  let res = checkAuth(token)


But the cookie that the server returns is an httpOnly cookie. And httpOnly cookies are not accessible by JS

@U.Watt Can you update your question with the updated code?
